# Sonar authenticate with token failed when using UTL_HTTP

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

I'm trying to invoke Sonar delete project API with UTL_HTTP (don't ask me why using oracle package, I have no choice).

I tested my command using curl and it is working fine:

```
curl -u c3b4gj1k11a12n726kjo0eaaf1d0035dt6afd7cg5d: -d "key=community.developer.scott" http://sonar:9000/api/projects/delete
```

but when I try to implement it in PL/SQL, I have an internal server error

```
declare
    l_command varchar2(2500) := 'http://sonar:9000/api/projects/delete?key=community.developer.scott';
    l_req      UTL_HTTP.req;
    l_response UTL_HTTP.resp;
begin

   l_req      := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(l_command, 'POST');
   UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_req,'Authorization','Basic c3b4gj1k11a12n726kjo0eaaf1d0035dt6afd7cg5d');

   l_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(l_req);
   if l_response.status_code != 200 then 
     display_msg('Error accessing to Sonar (error code: ' || l_response.status_code||')');
     display_msg('HTTP response reason phrase: ' || l_response.reason_phrase);
   end if;
   UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_response);
    exception
        when others then display_msg('Http detailed sqlerrm: '|| utl_http.GET_DETAILED_SQLERRM());
end;
```

below is the server log :

```
2017.11.20 17:55:44 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://sonar:9000/api/projects/delete?key=community.developer.scott
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:132:in `login_from_basic_auth'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/http_authentication.rb:126:in `authenticate'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/http_authentication.rb:116:in `authenticate_with_http_basic'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:129:in `login_from_basic_auth'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Sonarqube/web/WEB
```

Is someone know how to set the HTTP header to invoke Sonar API with token authentication ?

Comment: What SonarQube version do you use?

Comment: I use Sonar 5.6.6